# Can't get this break statement to work

Tags: python

I want to find the highest number not in the list. The break should end the last for loop and leave me with Ans = highest number not in list. Why doesn't it work

```
A = [1,3,5,9,11]

u = A[0]
for i in range(1, len(A)):
    if A[i] > u:
            u = A[i]
    if u <= 0:
        Ans = 1

    else:
        for j in range(u ,0, -1):
            if j not in A:
                Ans = j
                print(Ans)
                break
```

Comment: Your break statement only 'breaks' from the loop 'for j in range(u, 0, -1)'.. the outer loop will still run

Answer (score 1):

`break` gets you out of the inner loop, you also need to exit the outer one.  You could do this using a boolean flag, etc... but I prefer using a `for - else` construct

`for-else`, means `no break`, that is the loop will resume in the `else` attached to the `for` when there is no break in the inner loop, otherwise, it will execute the following.
`continue`, takes you to the end of the loop.

Now, it seems your logic may also have a problem, the answer printed is `2`

```
A = [1,3,5,9,11]

u = A[0]
for i in range(1, len(A)):
    if A[i] > u:
            u = A[i]
    if u <= 0:
        Ans = 1

    else:
        for j in range(u ,0, -1):
            if j not in A:
                Ans = j
                print(Ans)
                break
        else:    # <-- attention, this "else" must be aligned with the preceding "for", not the "if"
            continue
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, the `break` works fine, breaking from the loop it is in -- but not from the loop above that!

Alternatively to using `for/else` or moving the entire calculation into a function and using `return` instead of `break`, you could also replace the nested loop with a generator, lazily finding the `next` value that satisfies the condition. If that value is not `None` (the default), `break` from the outer loop.

```
    else:
        r = next((j for j in range(u ,0, -1) if j not in A), None)
        if r is not None:
            Ans = r
            print(Ans)
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `break` doesn't work, because your indentation for `if u <= 0:` and further is wrong.

```
A = [-1, -3, -5, -9, -11]
Ans = 1
for j in range(max(A)-1, max(0, min(A)), -1):
    if j not in A:
        Ans = j
        print(Ans)
        break
```

However, I advise you to use NumPy if your list is huge, because it is much faster.

```
# Find the highest number not in the list
import numpy as np

l = [1,3,5,9,11]
a = np.array(l)
ans = 1
for i in range(a.max()-1, max(0, a.min()), -1):
    if i not in a:
        ans = i
        print(i)
        break
```

Comment: What makes you think that the indentation is wrong?

Comment: @tobias_k obviously there is no need to set "Ans = 1" many times in the cycle. First, find max. Second, find value that is not in the list. These are 2 different operations.

Answer (score 1):

@ foo bar et al.

Seems the indentation was wrong as per your suggestions. While all your other suggestions were more elegant my solution turned out to be:

```
A = [1,3,5,9,11]

u = A[0]
for i in range(1, len(A)):
    if A[i] > u:
            u = A[i]
if u <= 0:
    Ans = 1
    print(Ans)

else:
    for j in range(u ,0, -1):
            if j not in A:
                Ans = j
                print(Ans)
                break
```

Comment: You could use u = max(A) -- it is shorter.